# certificate working on IP but not on URL

Tags: windows-phone-7, ssl-certificate, ie-mobile

I have a problem accessing my site (on https) with IEMobile 9 (WP 7.5).

It says it's got problem with the certificate, as if it wasn't valid. Everything works on any other browser or platform I tested (android (several phones and a galaxy tab with stock browser, firefox, opera, dolphin), iOS (iphone and ipad with safari and chrome), an old nokia with symbian, windows 7, linux and mac).

To try to solve this I saved the certificate (.cer) on the server and accessed it from the phone browser. It always complained except when I accessed it through the server IP (192.168.xx.xx). At that point it (said it) installed correctly the certificate. If then I try to access the index.html still using the IP all works fine and it doesn't complain about the certificate. If, though, I try to access the index using the actual URL (blah.myblah.com), it complains again about the certificate, as if it wasn't installed!

It isn't a problem of DNS, cause that's up and serving the right ip, and the phone is correctly setup to use it.

The certificate is signed by geotrust/rapidssl for *.myblah.com.

Comment: Have you tried clearing all of the caches? Cert errors are really bad, so it's possible that your browser is remembering that it is a bad place to be.

Comment: Yes, but it makes no difference. This happens on a real phone and on the emulator (on win7)

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what the error says? Also, this question might be better suited on serverfault.

Comment: it's not an error, but a generic security warning like this (only on IEMobile version): http://cdn.ttgtmedia.com/rms/misc/Exchange_2010_Mobile_2A.jpg
I will try and post the question on SF as well, then. I hope it's not considered as crossposting... :/

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. certificates are issued to a particular host+domain name. Basically, SSL's validation code will have something like

```
if (requested host name != certificate issued hostname) {
    issue security alert
}
```

so you're doing

```
if (192.168.xx.xx != example.com) {
```

and get the security warning.

Comment: I get NO security warning using the IP. I get it when using the URL, for which the certificate is issued

Comment: hmm. check that geotrust/rapidssl is in the phone's/browser's built-in CA list.

Comment: I did that (even though now I can't find out the link again, it was somewhere on MS website), and GeoTrust is there with 3 entries. My certificate has a SHA1 key, and one of those 3 was a SHA1. The others being a SH256 and something else I can't remember now.

Comment: found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28v=VS.92%29.aspx
having a better look at it my key isn't listed. Still, if I installed the certificate once, why doesn't it work on subsequent visits?

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with certificates related to how some HTTP over TLS implementations look for SubjectAltName(SAN). [RFC2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) states that, if the hostname is a DNS entry, implementations must check the hostname against the subjectAltName extension array looking for a DNS entry that matches the host. In case there's no subjectAltName CommonName is used.
If the hostname is an IP, the certificate must contain a subjectAltName IP entry matching the IP.
Also note that wildcard certificates are being discouraged by the newer [RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2), so MAYBE windows phone is already enforcing this, although I might be wrong.

My first step would be to check the SAN portion of the certificate and make sure it has a DNS entry matching the your site's host.